# How to make a method on a model that returns html to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a survey that has a bunch of different response types (BooleanResponse, TextResponse, etc.) via Single Table Inheritance. In my view, I'd really like to be able to call a method like `response.render` and have that return html code. Is this possible to do? What do I have to write in the method to make the return type compatible with an html.erb view?

(I know this can also be done in the view or the view helper with a long case/switch statement, but I'd much prefer to do it this way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do to make the method return html is to use [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe):

```
def method_that_returns_html
  data = '<strong>Your html here</strong>'
  data.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Would this work with erb? If not, is there a way to do this that would?

Comment: Yes, this will work with erb. I've already turned the computer off, but if you want, tomorrow I can look through my older projects for some erb examples (I now use HAML) - but it should be straight forward

Comment: I should be able to figure it out without examples, thanks!

Comment: This should not be done in the model. This should be a helper method or partial.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to understand that now. Is there a way to implement this in a helper other than a long if statement that has one branch for each subclass of Response?